# jquery .change event on select tag working weird on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have an AJAX system setup that helps the user to select a state and then select the respective city and zipcodes.

The problem is the `.change()` event not working on chrome. As long as I use my mouse and do any kind of working, it is all good, but the moment I switch to keyboard, it dies. The `.change()` event gets fired with every click on the keyboard.

The same script works fine in Firefox. The mouse working here is same as chrome. But when I use the keyboard, it doesn't triggers the `.change()` event. It triggers it on blur or when enter key is pressed.

I am looking for a workaround for chrome, so that it starts to work the same way Firefox works.

I haven't tested other browsers yet.

Edit:
I am not willing to use `.blur()` or `.click()` events as that would be more pain for the normal user because if by mistake they click or skip a select tag without changing the value the ajax will be fired again.

My code is all good.

```
$('#state').change(function(event) {});
```

This line is supposed to work on change event and it does until I use my keyboard on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you bind both the change and keypress event and that should get you working on all the browsers.. thus define your callback function instead of it being anonymous.

```
function changeCallback(){}

$("#state").change(changeCallback).keypress(changeCallback);
```

Comment: You can also use `.bind()` to have them both.

Comment: I dont't want to have them both. I want to stop change event from being triggered, if it is also a keydown event.